# Can I make a selective refresh of the contents in the JSP page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, page-refresh, partial-page-refresh

It seems to be weird but still :

Is there any way I can make only the  selective portion of the jsp page get refreshed ? Suppose :

```
<% response.setIntHeader("Refresh",1); // refresh at an interval of 1 second %>

<!-- Html5 snippet that plays a sound that lasts more than a second !-->

<% jsp code %>
```

Now, I want when the page gets refreshed the audio clip starts from where it left. Is that possible ? The clip's size is **2.4 MB** ?

Comment: you could refresh the certain regions clientside per javascript/ajax. All other regions would be untouched. Then the clip would also keep on playing while the regions are refreshing.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I know only java and a bit of javascript

Comment: @SuhailGupta Learning new technologies is something useful for you :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad yeah..but i wanted to do this just know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Jquery to refresh perticular div element in JSP

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>

<body>
  <div id="load_tweets"> </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT1**

**reload-window.jsp**  // place this file in beside WEB-INF

```
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@page import="java.util.GregorianCalendar"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%! GregorianCalendar newYear = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 1);

    /*
     * 0 : January
     * 1 : 1st January
     * 2013 : year
     */%>
        <div>
        Time : 
        <%= (newYear.getTimeInMillis() - new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()) / 1000%>
        </div>
```

**main.jsp**

```
<%-- 
    Document   : nyblast
    Created on : Dec 26, 2012, 10:44:27 AM
    Author     : non-admin
--%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#73AF59">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var auto_refresh = setInterval(
            function ()
            {
                $('#load_tweets').load('reload-window.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
            }, 5000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

          </script>



<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="40%"></td>
        <td><img src="images/animations/pyear.gif" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">
        <center><font face="Chiller" size="+6"> <br />
        Countdown </font></center>
        </td>
        <td>
        <center><font face="Chiller" size="+6"> <br />

        <div id="load_tweets"></div>
        </font></center>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="height: 400px" valign="bottom"><img
            src="images/animations/3D_balloons.gif" /> <em>This poor design
        and animations compiled by Suhail Gupta.</em> <audio
            style="visibility: hidden"> </audio></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- !-->
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

here the problem

```
$('#load_tweets').load('reload-window.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
                }, 5000); // refresh every 5000 milliseconds
```

load function we need to pass our JSP which need to refresh

Make sure your js is located to right palce.

Comment: I do not see what I place inside the div tag. [code snippet](http://i45.tinypic.com/no8ujd.png)

Comment: what could be the reason for this ?

Comment: Here is the [complete code](http://suhail3.my3gb.com/nyblast%20(copy).jsp). It is a simple code that has to display the seconds. _( From inside that div tag )_ But it is not doing so

Comment: Will you please comment on my comment ! ?